# Extract text from a text file with Chinese characters using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a batch of like 100,000 text files which I would like to extract as strings using vba.
In the past I have been doing so this way without problem:

```
Sub Main()
Dim PathAndName As String
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim TextString() As String
Redim TextString(100000)
For i = 1 To 100,000
    PathAndName = "C:\File_" & i & ".ext"
    TextFile = 1
    Open PathAndName For Input As TextFile
    TextString(i) = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
Next i
End Sub
```

This time, the script returns the error "Input Past End of File" Error 62.
The only different I can spot is that this time the text files contain a few Chinese Characters, which are not of my interest actually. That's why I believe this is the source of the problem.
The Chinese Characters appear at the first line of the files.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for missing out. The Chinese Characters are also present on the 3rd last line.

Comment: `PathAndName = "C:\File_" & i & ".ext"` should be `PathAndName = "C:\File_" & i & ".txt"`. and add `Close TextFile`before `Next i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your text file is in a multibyte encoding now. There one character is encoded in two or three bytes. So `LOF(TextFile)` will not return the correct character count but the byte count. But `Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)` needs the character count since it must create a `String`.

You could use:

```
Sub Main()
Dim PathAndName As String
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim TextString() As String
Redim TextString(100000)
For i = 1 To 100000
    PathAndName = "C:\File_" & i & ".ext"
    TextFile = 1
    Open PathAndName For Input As TextFile

    Dim sLine As String
    Dim sTextString As String
    sLine = ""
    sTextString = ""

    Do While Not EOF(TextFile)
     Input #TextFile, sLine
     sTextString = sTextString & sLine
    Loop

    TextString(i) = sTextString

    Close #TextFile

Next i
End Sub
```

But the better approach would be using `ADODB.Stream` instead of the dinosaur VB file access methods. But this is a totally different approach. So you should read about `ADODB.Stream` yourself first.