# How to read .txt file with Chinese characters?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a subroutine that reads text files and extracts certain data from them. Here is an example:

```
NamePrefix = "Example"
OutputPath = "C:\Example"
DbSize = 65536

LstStr = ""
Dim Success() As Boolean
Dim Value() As Double
ReDim Success(1 to DbSize)
ReDim Value(1 to DbSize)
For ID = 1 to DbSize
  'Read string
    FileName = NamePrefix & Format(ID,"000000") & ".lst"
    FilePath = OutputPath & "\" & FileName
    Open FilePath For Input As 1
    LstStr = Input(LOF(1),1)
    Close 1
  'Extract data
    If InStr(1, LstStr, "SUCCESS") <> 0 Then Success(i) = True Else Success(i) = False
    Pos1 = InStr(1, LstStr, "TH 1 value: ") 'Position varies for each file
    Value(i) = Val(Mid(LstStr, Pos1 + 13, 10)) 'Value in scientific notation
Next ID
```

The use of *InStr* to locate strings by position works perfectly when there are just alphabets, numbers and symbols. However, sometimes the files contain Chinese characters and the *Input* function returns an empty string "" to *LstStr*. I tried to use some other suggested methods but in vain (e.g. [Extract text from a text file with Chinese characters using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961611/extract-text-from-a-text-file-with-chinese-characters-using-vba)). How should I read files with Chinese characters successfully, in a way that I do not need to modify other parts of the code which extract data by position? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use an `ADODB.Stream` (with the correct charset) instead of the VBA file access methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an alternative way to read the string. Make sure that the `.Charset` is set to the charset of the file you want to read.

> To use ADOBD you will need to add the reference *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library* (Version can be different) in VBA Menu › Extras › References

```
Dim adoStream As ADODB.Stream
Set adoStream = New ADODB.Stream

adoStream.Charset = "UTF-8" 'set the correct charset
adoStream.Open
adoStream.LoadFromFile FilePath

LstStr = adoStream.ReadText

adoStream.Close
Set adoStream = Nothing
```

Comment: For Japanese utf-8 don't work for me. I found that shift-jis charset works corectly for it.